# How to convert a Date column currently as 01/01/00 to 01/01/2000

Tags: r, date, data-cleaning

I am working a dataset which has a Date column currently stored as Character, below is the format of how the dates are:

31/12/00

01/01/01

I want to change the year part from "00" to "2000" and "01" to "2001" for the whole column and want it in date format.

How can I do it?

[image]

I tried doing the following way

```
if(y2k_clean$Date[7:8] == "00")
  replace(y2k_clean$Date, 7, "2000")
```

I also tried to achieve this with `gsub()` but could not get the result I wanted.

Thank you.

Comment: How do we know that `00` corresponds to `2000` and not `1900` ?

Comment: Please don't post your data as images and instead post them as code (ie, using `dput()`)

Comment: Hi Nihar Patel. Welcome to SO! Please add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) instead of posting pictures. That said, you could do: `y2k_clean$new_Date <- gsub("(\\d{2})$", "20\\1", y2k_clean$Date)`, but I expect that you'd be better off by converting to a `date`-type soon :-)

Comment: Do you want it as date formatted or character formatted?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Hello Tim I know the data set is about the year 2000-2001 so I want it converted to those values.

Comment: @jpsmith Sure mate, will do that from now on. I want is in Date format. Thanks.

Comment: @harre Hello, will have a look at how add a reproducible code. Thanks for the info and also for the code and guidance.

Comment: NiharPatel, you say you want it in "Date format", which means you cannot display it in R as `%d/%m/%Y`. R displays dates always and only as `%Y-%m-%d`. If you want to render it in a report as `%d/%m/%Y`, that's fine, but I suggest you keep it `Date`-class (Ymd) as long as possible and convert to dmY only when rendering the table/plot/report. There are ways around this, but they are incomplete, rife with corner-cases, and generally too much work and risk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first convert it to a `date` with the format and after that convert it to your format with `%Y` as 4 digit year like this:

```r
dates <- c('31/12/00', '01/01/01')
format(as.Date(dates,format='%d/%m/%y'), "%d/%m/%Y")
#> [1] "31/12/2000" "01/01/2001"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hello Quinten, that worked for me they are now in format I want. Can you explain the part after (format = '%d/%m/%y') this is used for current format? and then we convert the year with "%Y". How did it take "00" as 2000? Thank you.

Comment: Hi @NiharPatel, %y is year with 2 digits like 01 and %Y is year with 4 digits like 2001.

Answer (score 0):

You can use format:

```
df <- tibble(Date = c("31/12/00", "01/01/01"))
format(as.Date(df$Date, format="%d/%m/%y"))
```